# Always get None from Django api request as result

Tags: python, django, api

I am going to get `whitebg_url` result from sqlite database according to matched items and made the api request using django like this.

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def getUrlFromAttributes(request):

    try: 
        print('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>', request)
        hairstyle = request.data.get("hairstyle")
        haircolor = request.data.get("haircolor")
        skincolor = request.data.get("skincolor")
        print("error>>1", str(hairstyle), str(haircolor), str(skincolor))

        basic_query = BasicSetup.objects.all().filter(skin_color=skincolor, hair_color=haircolor, hair_style=hairstyle, isDeleted= 0)
        print('returned basic query : ', basic_query)
        lists_basicSetup = list(basic_query.values( 'whitebg_url'))
        print('returned lists_basicSetup : ', lists_basicSetup)
        return JsonResponse({'result': lists_basicSetup})       
    except Exception as error:
        print("error", str(error))       
        return JsonResponse({'result': str(error)})
```

But as you can see the result at the below image, response is always None.
I tried to find the solution from google, but can't do it.

[image]

I already add `rest_framework` at INSTALLED_APPS in `settings.py` file.

and path is like defined.
`path('getUrlFromAttributes', views.getUrlFromAttributes, name='getUrlFromAttributes'),`

I tried to do this using Postman, but the result was same.

[image]

Anyone knows why I was getting `None` as result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get request body as bytes and parse using JSONParser.
I just edited your code as below:

```
import io
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser

# Create your views here.
@api_view(['POST'])
def getView(request, *args, **kwargs):

    try: 
        # you can get byte data from request body
        print('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>', request.body)

        # get bytes and parse using json 
        # do these before
        byte_body = io.BytesIO(request.body)
        parsed_body = JSONParser().parse(byte_body)
        
        hairstyle = parsed_body.get("hairstyle")
        haircolor = parsed_body.get("haircolor")
        skincolor = parsed_body.get("skincolor")
        print("error>>1", str(hairstyle), str(haircolor), str(skincolor))

        basic_query = BasicSetup.objects.all().filter(skin_color=skincolor, hair_color=haircolor, hair_style=hairstyle, isDeleted= 0)
        print('returned basic query : ', basic_query)
        lists_basicSetup = list(basic_query.values( 'whitebg_url'))
        print('returned lists_basicSetup : ', lists_basicSetup)
        return JsonResponse({'result': lists_basicSetup})       
    except Exception as error:
        print("error", str(error))       
        return JsonResponse({'result': str(error)})
```

Just as a friend if you can, use class-based views and serializers.

Answer (score 0):

The GET parameters are not stored in `request.data`. Check `request.GET`. See [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Image with post parameters in url]

Take a look at the (your) image above.
Do you notice the Hairstyle, haircolor skincolor, etc parameters in the url?

That happens with a GET request. Yes, the log shows POST, meaning a POST event did happen.

There's all likeness that your data aren't actually POSTed, that's why you don't get them in the view function.

Suggestions:

1. Cross check your JS file responsible for the POSTing (you can share here if you want).
2. Try grabbing the parameters off the url instead (GET method, if non-sensitive information) if Your POSTing isn't working, just to test my theory.

> request.query_params

3. Read again [Django RestFrameworks oc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/)